# Executing IF statement in Where clause SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm looking to only return rows where if my first condition doesn't exist
then return new condition from same table, and additional conditions:
basically...:

```
SELECT *   
FROM Table1     
WHERE

Condition#1: Column1=Column2

Condition#2: AND IF Column1 = Column2 doesn't exist (matching values for same ID) 
             THEN return results where Column3 = Column4
```

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: what you mean  column1 = column2 doesnt exist?

Comment: what's wrong with `WHERE Column1=Column2 OR Column3 = Column4`?

Comment: Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @scsimon My guess is if doesnt exist any rows with col1 = col2 then return rows where col3 = col4 but not sure

Comment: should work though @JuanCarlosOropeza no? If c1=c2 and c3=c4 that's the same as either one of the conditions being met, so i don't see how that where clause would fail a use case but who knows lol

Comment: @scsimon not because if you have rows with c1 = c2 then you shouldnt show the one with c3=c4 (unless they already have c1 = c2) but again is just guessing

Comment: oh i see what you mean

Comment: sorry, if matching values don't exist in the table THEN only return results where values in Column3 = Values in Column4

Comment: again show us an example with data so we can know for sure what you want.

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: My answer covers your scenarios.

Comment: @Johnsonium Your answer doesnt cover the first case.   because `A <> B` and `100 = 100` and the row shouldnt be on the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to check what case you are. So you count how many `C1 = C2` you have in your table

```
SELECT [id], COUNT(CASE WHEN C1 = C2 THEN 1 END) as c1_c2
FROM Table1
GROUP BY [id]
```

Then you have two conditions

first when you have some c1 = c2 you do

```
  (c1 = c2 and c1_c2 > 0 )
```

and the second when dont have any c1 = c2

```
  (c1_c2 = 0 and c3 = c4)
```

**[SQL DEMO:](https://rextester.com/TZJFO18841)**: Because is an `OR` and the c1_c2 count decide which side of the where is going to work.

```
WITH c12 as (
    SELECT [id], COUNT(CASE WHEN C1 = C2 THEN 1 END) as c1_c2_cnt
    FROM Table1
    GROUP BY [id]
) 
SELECT *
FROM Table1 T
JOIN c12 C
  ON T.[id] = C.[id]  
WHERE  ( C.c1_c2_cnt > 0 and T.c1 = T.c2 )
   OR  ( C.c1_c2_cnt = 0 and T.c3 = T.c4 )
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that this will work for what the OP is after, however, the logic seems odd...

```
SELECT {Columns}
FROM YourTable YT
WHERE YT.Column1 = YT.Column2
   OR (YT.Column3 = YT.Column4
  AND  NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1
                  FROM YourTable e
                  WHERE YT.id = e.id
                    AND e.Column1 = e.Column2));
```

Not sure how good the performance will be here though, as you may well end up with a table scan with that `NOT EXISTS`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, based off the comments, here is one way.

```
SELECT *    
FROM Table1      
WHERE Column1 = Column2 
UNION 
SELECT * 
FROM Table2 
WHERE  Column1 != Column2 and Column3 = Column4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using simple booleans:

```
WHERE
Column1 = Column2
OR
Column3 = Column4
```

The Venn diagram for this:

[image]

All of the shaded area will be returned, including when Column1 = Column2 & Column3 = Column4 (the dark shaded intersection)

If you don't want rows where both conditions are met then you can modify the logic:

```
WHERE
Column1 = Column2
OR
(Column1 <> Column2 
AND
Column3 = Column4)
```

The Venn would look the same except the intersection would be white and excluded.

Comment: colum3 = colum4 only if doesnt exist any match for column1 = column2

Comment: Yes. This covers it. If the first condition returns false then the second condition will be evaluated. If that is true then the whole thing returns true and the row is returned. The only rows excluded are ones where neither condition is true.

Comment: doesnt work like that. the first condition has to return false for all rows before you can consider the second codition

Comment: That isn't clear above. And even if it is you can simply modify the logic slightly: Column1 = Column2 OR (Column1 <> Column2 AND Column3 = Column4). The Venn would then have the intersection white and excluded.

Comment: again, you need consider second condition if first condition fail for all rows. check my answer. I first calculate the count to see what case I have

Comment: No. It's not necessary at all. Think in sets. That's what SQL does. Either a row is in or out of the result set. WHERE clauses determine which is the case. All the extra logic is unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach :

```
DECLARE 
    @t TABLE( ID INT, col1 CHAR(1), col2 CHAR(1), col3 INT, col4 INT)

INSERT INTO @t VALUES 
(1234,'A','B',100,100),
(1234,'A','A',100,100),
(2468,'A','C',125,125),
(2468,'A','B',100,150)

SELECT 
    ID
,   col1
,   col2
,   col3
,   col4
FROM (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID, col1 ORDER BY col2) RN
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM @t
        WHERE 
            col3 = col4
        AND col1 = col2
        UNION ALL 
        SELECT *
        FROM @t
        WHERE 
            col3 = col4
        AND ID NOT IN(
            SELECT ID
            FROM @t
            WHERE 
                col3 = col4
            AND col1 = col2
            )
    ) D
) E
WHERE 
    RN = 1
```

Comment: check this example https://rextester.com/HAMK64548 just change `(A,A)` for `(C,C)` and you wont get the desire output

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, I guess this will work as expected.